# Сортировка класса в PHP

Tags: php

Имею класс PHP с объектами:

- id Цена
- 1 200
- 1 300
- 1 400
- 2 500
- 2 400
- 2 300

(грубо говоря id - это классификатор товара)

С помощью каких функций в PHP я могу оставить в классе (или сделать выборку) объекты c минимальными ценами по каждому товару

Т.е. чтобы осталось следующее:

- id Цена
- 1 200
- 2 300

Comment: Данные наверняка берутся из БД, так? Если нет, то как это выглядит в переменной?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, да берутся в БД но потом обрабатываются и в этот класс записывается уже конечный результат. Теперь задача как отсортировать этот класс.

Comment: Во-первых: что значит `как отсортировать этот класс.`? Во-вторых, если задача уже не актуальна и есть другая задача - надо задавать другой вопрос. В третьих, по поводу данной задачи: достаточно выбирать из БД данные уже сгруппированные по id и выбранным минимальным значением. Тогда действия в *PHP* вообще **не потребуются**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что мешает сделать обычный цикл, и удалять не нужные, или формировать новый класс который будет выведен в конце. Вам нужны только циклы это фундаментальные знания, думаю, найдется достаточно примеров. foreach или while

```
for ($i=0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    if ($min > ${'item_'.$i}->Price || empty($min))
    {
        $min_obj = ${'item_'.$i};
        $min = ${'item_'.$i}->Price;
    }
}
var_dump($min_obj);
```

**Вариант 2:**

```
for ($i=0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        // находим минимум, крайний!
        if ($min > ${'item_'.$i}->Price || empty($min))
    {
        $min_obj = ${'item_' . $i};
        $min = ${'item_'.$i}->Price;
                $min_name = 'item_' . $i;
    }

        // находим максимум, крайний!
        if ($max < ${'item_'.$i}->Price || empty($max))
        {
                $max_obj = ${'item_'.$i};
                $max = ${'item_'.$i}->Price;
                $max_name = 'item_' . $i;
        }

        //Кол-во
        $col++;

        // Среднее
        $sred = $sred + ${'item_'.$i}->Price;

}

echo "<p>Всего элементов: <strong style='color: red'>", $col ,"</strong></p>";

echo "<p>Средняя сумма: <strong style='color: red'>", $sred / $col ,"</strong></p>";

echo "<p>Минимум <strong style='color: red'>", $min_name ,"</strong> = <strong style='color: red'>", $min, "</strong> id = <strong style='color: red'>", $min_obj->id, "</strong> полные данные об объекте: <strong style='color: red'>", var_dump($min_obj), "</strong></p>";

echo "<p>Максимум <strong style='color: red'>", $max_name ,"</strong> = <strong style='color: red'>", $max, "</strong> id = <strong style='color: red'>", $max_obj->id, "</strong> полные данные об объекте: <strong style='color: red'>", var_dump($max_obj), "</strong></p>";
```

Comment: я знаком с фундаментальными алгортимами, но все же не могу понять, как сортируется класс циклами... Но спасибо, буду искать ответ в этом направлении.

Comment: Исходя из описания выше, у вас не класс а массив с данными из ДБ, или что конкретно вы хотите сортировать напишите пример я напишу код.

Comment: да нет же, именно класс, я вот набросал пример по своему примеру http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d71b39f05b1338a48c853e5fc979a9381d75a48b

Comment: В данном коде класс один а есть объекты с 1 по 5 их и нужно проверять, оставив только нужное. Положил код выше.

Comment: спасибо, а где берется переменная $min?

Comment: $min = ${'item_'.$i}->Price; а так если ее нет, ее создает скрипт

Comment: разобрался с кодом, спасибо, я уже отметил что ответ правильный за вашу помощь. Но он позволяет лишь находить объект с минимальной ценой из одной категории товаров (скажем с id=1), а мне нужно найти минимальную цену среди  id=1 и  id=2, и этих  id может быть много. Не подскажите как действовать в этом случае?

Comment: я уже думаю, может мне в массив этот класс перегнать и уже его пытаться сортировать

Comment: Я бы добавил еще одну или две проверки во время перебора и в конце выдавал результат, я то показал пример а дальше можно делать что угодно.

Comment: последняя просьба: а можете в ваш код дописать еще одну переменную, а я уже по аналогии дальше сам буду думать

Comment: Ну так а задача второй части какая?

Comment: ну еще раз, ваш код находит минимальную цену вообще среди всех объектов, а нужно же найти объект с минимальной ценой среди товаров с id=1, и другой объект с минимальной ценой среди товаров с id=2, ну а вобще этих id может быть и больше

Comment: Добавил еще вариантов, находит кол-во, среднее число, минимум и максимум. По поводу того сколько этих элементов то задавайте максимум не 6 а кол-во элементов. Сколько их нужно знать иначе не получится узнать сколько именно переменных создано.

Comment: спасибо. В принципе на основании вашего кода я сделал то что хотел, но я все перегнал в двухмерные массивы, а дальше по вашему принципу используя динамические именна наполнял итоговый массив с результатами, работает замечательно, спасибо еще раз.

Comment: только я empty($max) заменил на !isset($max), а  то PHP выдает предупреждение